# When opening an output file how does the filename get attached to the constructor if there's no field for it?

Tags: java, file, filewriter

When you open an output file in Java, where does the name of the file get attached to the constructor if there is no field for it? Or does it just get attached to the file?

```
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);
             //Where does the filename go? I haven't had 
             //a good example of the outputfile's constructors in class
```

Comment: No idea what you are asking. The code **behind** that ctor does what it needs to do. In other words: maybe you want to study the PrintWriter source code?

Answer (score 0):

It's passed to the Outputstream you pass as a parameter for the Writer. Example:

```
    try (final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new   File("filename"))) {
        final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
    }
```

Comment: The OP (apparently) passed a file name, not a `FileOutputStream`

Comment: the point is that when using the `(String)` constructor the `FileOutputStream` is constructed _internally_ to the `PrintWriter`, not passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

When passed a `String` (containing the intended file name) the `PrintWriter` constructor will internally create a `FileOutputStream` that is itself constructed using that file name.

It will then create an `OutputStreamWriter` that refers to the stream, retaining a (protected) reference to that writer, e.g. (in simplified form, without error checking):

```
protected Writer out;

public PrintWriter(String filename) {
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    out = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
}
```

All subsequent output is done via the `out` member variable, and the `PrintWriter` has no further use for the filename, hence why there's no member variable associated with it.

Answer (score -1):

The string you pass in the constructor is the full file' path, i.e. `/data/my-file.txt`.

If the file exists, you'll override its content. Otherwise, you'll create it and write inside it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another example:

```
    FileWriter fstream;
    try {
        fstream = new FileWriter("1111.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write ("line 11111\r\n");
        out.write("line 1222\r\n");
        out.write("line 33\r\n");
        out.close();            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```